# I have a tiff that errors in java "Error found: No reference line present." What gives?

Tags: java, image-processing, tiff

ImageReader.read throws an IOException opening a tiff file:

```
    javax.imageio.IIOException: No reference line present.
        at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFFaxDecompressor.decodeT4(TIFFFaxDecompressor.java:903)
        at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFFaxDecompressor.decodeRaw(TIFFFaxDecompressor.java:677)
        at com.sun.media.imageio.plugins.tiff.TIFFDecompressor.decode(TIFFDecompressor.java:2514)
        at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReader.decodeTile(TIFFImageReader.java:1137)
        at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReader.read(TIFFImageReader.java:1417)
        at javax.imageio.ImageReader.read(ImageReader.java:940)
```

I can open the image fine though in windows photo viewer, gimp, mspaint, etc. Anyone have a clue what might cause this, or how to redress?

Comment: from th [sourcecode](http://dev.loci.wisc.edu/trac/software/browser/trunk/components/jai/src/com/sun/media/imageioimpl/plugins/tiff/TIFFFaxDecompressor.java?rev=4503) it appears that the parser hit the end of the file before finding a specific line.

Comment: Do you know where I could get that source file? I can't find the imageioimpl classes in the https://svn.java.net/svn/jai-core~svn/ repository.Edit: (found the answer with a little googling)[http://dev.loci.wisc.edu/trac/software/browser/trunk/components/jai/src/com/sun/media/imageioimpl/plugins/tiff/TIFFFaxDecompressor.java?rev=4503]

Comment: @user364902: Actually, I think the loci/scifio project has moved to GitHub: https://github.com/scifio/bioformats/tree/develop/components/forks/jai (although the JAI source code is probably not modified)